# Changing data symbol when using ECharts dataset format

Tags: echarts

ECharts allows defining different [`symbol`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.data.symbol) for each data point when using [`series.data`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.data) option like in [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurGAJ4gCmRA5JALZW0kC-ANCeTvkaqWUo1YtAG4BDADYBXZm07o8VAE4QqhWAG0S6fgNh5yDAEbBJAZQgAvYQFYADJx2kAJuLDii2_aSSwJMsKatABM9iEAzAC09gCMMbEAKrG2BPb2afYAWrTssLH2ALp5hiZmdADGEMoVksywHM4CfgGyXqHh0XEJyQBsmZk5eWHFBkamknTKVBVgtA0KPsj-Um1aHZEJPbEA7APpQ_m2o6UTdGCq4tAA5nXzrE2wxY8U1HSSENByAg_ohSisADcQA):

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time'
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      symbolSize: 50,
      data: [
        { value: ['2023-01-01T15:00:00Z', 10], symbol: 'circle' },
        { value: ['2023-01-01T16:00:00Z', 20], symbol: 'rect' },
        { value: ['2023-01-01T17:00:00Z', 15], symbol: 'triangle' }
      ],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
};
```

This could be used e.g. to display weather symbol in a weather forecast chart. The example defines data under series, however it seems to be an older approach and now it is recommended to use [datasets](https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/concepts/dataset/) instead.

How to set the symbol per datapoint when providing data in [`dataset.source`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataset.source)?

Answer (score 0):

[`series.symbol`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.symbol) can be a callback function which can access the data from dataset and return different symbol for each data point:

> If symbols needs to be different, you can set with callback function
> in the following format:
>
> (value: Array|number, params: Object) => string The first parameter
> value is the value in data, and the second parameter params is the
> rest parameters of data item.

So using dataset and callback, the code becomes:

```js
option = {
  dataset: {
    source: [
      // Each entry has 3rd value set to the symbol name.
      ['2023-01-01T15:00:00Z', 10, 'circle'],
      ['2023-01-01T16:00:00Z', 20, 'rect'],
      ['2023-01-01T17:00:00Z', 15, 'triangle'],
    ]
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time'
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      symbolSize: 50,
      // The first parameter 'value' is the entry in dataset.
      // 3rd value (value[2]) is the symbol name.
      symbol: (value, params) => value[2],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
};
```